# XSL hyperlink to another XML part

Tags: xml, xslt

I generate 2 different XML files.
The first one is a summary of test sequences. Here is a part of the XML:

```
<Test_Sequence name="TX0_EVM_LTE_20MHz" status="PASS">
    <Waveform>LTE_20M_TM-15dBFs_TM3_1.aw2s</Waveform>
    <Duration>02:38 min</Duration>
</Test_Sequence>
<Test_Sequence name="TX0_EVM_LTE_10MHz" status="FAIL">
    <Waveform>LTE_10M_TM-15dBFs_TM3_1.aw2s</Waveform>
    <Duration>01:14 min</Duration>
</Test_Sequence>
```

The second one is the test sequence results. Here is a part of the XML:

```
<Test_Sequence name="TX0_EVM_LTE_20MHz" status="PASS">
    <result lowerlimit="-150.00" name="Sensitivity"    upperlimit="-101.50">-106.93</result>
    <result lowerlimit="0.00"    name="EVM PDSCH Mean" upperlimit="8.00">5.31</result>
    <result lowerlimit="-0.50"   name="PDetect"        upperlimit="0.50">0.35</result>
</Test_Sequence>
<Test_Sequence name="TX0_EVM_LTE_10MHz" status="FAIL">
    <result lowerlimit="-150.00" name="Sensitivity"    upperlimit="-101.50">-106.77</result>
    <result lowerlimit="0.00"    name="EVM PDSCH Mean" upperlimit="8.00">5.34</result>
    <result lowerlimit="-0.50"   name="PDetect"        upperlimit="0.50">0.38</result>
</Test_Sequence>
```

I can generate a HTML page with the summary.

[image]

Here is a part of the xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="Test_Sequence" mode="TestSummary">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="not(contains(@name, 'StartUp'))
                                    and not(contains(@name, 'Calibration'))">
                            <a href="#{generate-id()}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                            </a>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </td>

                <td> <xsl:value-of select="Duration"/> </td>
                <td> <xsl:value-of select="Waveform"/> </td>

                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test = "@status = 'PASS'">
                        <td style="color:green">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@status"/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <td style="color:red">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@status"/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </tr>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="not(contains(@name, 'StartUp'))
                                    and not(contains(@name, 'Calibration'))">
                            <a href="#{generate-id()}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                            </a>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </td>

                <td> <xsl:value-of select="Duration"/> </td>
                <td> <xsl:value-of select="Waveform"/> </td>

                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test = "@status = 'PASS'">
                        <td style="color:green">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@status"/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <td style="color:red">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@status"/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </tr>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Because the test results xml file is very huge, I can't display all the data on a single html page.
That's why my idea is to create a hyperlink between the test sequence name and the associated results and display them in a new HTML page.

The link will display a new HTML page with the results of the test sequence name.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You can use the `document()` function to refer to another document. Please post your XSLT so far and the expected result (**as code**, not as a picture). -- Note also that both the files you show are not XML, because they do not have a single root element.

Comment: I would recommend to go about it like that: Write your XSLT so that it loads all the detail files using `document()`, just as Michael suggests, and build a single HTML from it. Then use CSS and Javascript to toggle detail sections on or off. This way you the summary page is interactive and self-contained (i.e. no web server necessary to display it).

Comment: How are you initializing the transformation? Is there a link to the stylesheet in the first XML?

Comment: I create the XML and do the transformation with Java.